# linking a standard contact form to php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, email

i recently purchased a web template but the contact form is just a set of labels....no php form came with this so how do i set this up...

I've had to upload the image screenshot as it wouldn't let me add the code on here..
[contact form](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/6528/emailfo.jpg)

Comment: The site strips out HTML tags from posts.  To post code here, paste it in, then highlight it and press `Ctrl+k` or press the `{ }` button above the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a server script to email it out.  Seems like what you have just an HTML form.

[Use PHP to email Form](http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php)

Here is a simple tutorial on how to use PHP to email contact form.

Comment: Yeh it's just a html form at the moment (that came with the template) i don't want to use another form because it's just longing the process out for me... how do i go about setting up the html form i have atm linking a server script to it

Comment: set the form action to a server script use method=POST

Answer (score 0):

[Use mailto form action.](http://apptools.com/rants/mailto.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the form "action" to formProcess.php or similar, but you'd need to do some reading up on PHP form handling